# Multiple has_many through associations between same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have some doubts about the design of the database for a rails app that is used to record soccer (football) matches' statistics.

I have three models:

- Match
- Player
- Goal

which have the following relations:

- Every match can have many goals scored by players of the home team
- Every match can have many goals scored by players of the visitor team
- Each player (of the home and the visitor team) can score many goals in a match

Here is my models' structure:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_goals,
       class_name: 'Goal',
       foreign_key: 'home_match_id'
  has_many :home_scorers,
       class_name: 'Player',
       foreign_key: 'home_scorer_id',
       through: :home_goals

  has_many :visitor_goals,
       class_name: 'Goal',
       foreign_key: 'visitor_match_id'
  has_many :visitor_scorers,
       class_name: 'Player',
       foreign_key: 'visitor_scorer_id',
       through: :visitor_goals

  ...

end


class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_match,
      class: 'Match',
      foreign_key: 'home_match_id'
  belongs_to :visitor_match,
      class: 'Match',
      foreign_key: 'visitor_match_id'

  belongs_to :player
end


class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :goals
  has_many :home_matches,
      class_name: 'Match',
      foreign_key: 'home_scorer_id',
      through: :goals

  has_many :visitor_matches,
      class_name: 'Match',
      foreign_key: 'visitor_scorer_id',
      through: :goals

  ...

end
```

1. Can I do nested "has_many_through" relations in this way?
2. The unusual thing is that a player can score more than one goal in a match. Because of this it is possible that there are more than one goals with same player and same match.
   Is this possible or can cause errors?
3. My ultimate "goal" is to be able to count how many goals scored a player in all matches, get the list of home players, home goals, visitor players and visitor goals for each match. Is there a better way to organize the DB?

Comment: Why don't you try all that in `rails console`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like a Polymorphic Association. This basically allows a model to have multiple `belongs_to` The rails docs has good information on it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

with this, goals can belong to both players and matches and can let the players `has_many` and matches `has_many` be a lot more clean.